# Sf2 : using a service inside an entity

Tags: symfony, service, entities

i know this has been asked over and over again, i read the topics, but it's always focused on specific cases and i generally try to understand why its not best practise to use a service inside an entity.

Given a very simple service :

```
Class Age
{
  private $date1;
  private $date2;
  private $format;

  const ym = "%y years and %m month"
  const ...


  // some DateTime()->diff() methods, checking, formating the entry formats, returning different period formats for eg.
  }
```

and a simple entity :

```
Class People
{
  private $firstname;
  private $lastname;
  private $birthday;

  }
```

From a controller, i want to do :

```
$som1 = new People('Paul', 'Smith', '1970-01-01');
$som1->getAge();
```

Off course i can rewrite the `getAge()` function inside my entity, its not long, but im very lazy and as i've already written all the possible datetime->diff() i need in the above service, i dont understand why i shouldnt use'em...

NB : my question isnt about how to inject the container in my entity, i can understand why this doesnt make sense, but more what wld be the best practise to avoid to rewrite the same function in different entities.

Inheritance seems to be a bad "good idea" as i could use the getAge() inside a class BlogArticle and i doubt that this BlogArticle Class should be inheriting from the same class as a People class...

Hope i was clear, but not sure...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

One major confusion for many coders is to think that doctrine entities *"are"* the model. **That is a mistake.**

- See edit of this post at the end, incorporating ideas related to CQRS+ES -

Injecting services into your doctrine entities is a symptom of *"trying to do more things than storing data"* into your entities. When you see that *"anti-pattern"* most probably you are violating the *"Single Responsibility"* principle in SOLID programming.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle )

Symfony is not an `MVC` framework, it is a `VC` framework only. Lacks the `M` part. Doctrine entities (I'll call them entities from now on, see clarification at the end) are a *"data persistence layer",* not a *"model layer".* Symfony has lots of things for views, web controllers, command controllers... but has no help for domain modelling ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model ) - even the persistence layer is Doctrine, not Symfony.

**Overcoming the problem in SF2**

When you "need" services in a data-layer, trigger an antipattern alert. Storage should be only a "put here - get from there" system. Nothing else.

To overcome this problem, you should inject the services into a *"logic layer" (Model)* and separate it from *"pure storage" (data-persistence layer).* Following the single responsibility principle, put the logics in one side, put the getters and setters to MySQL in another.

The solution is to create the missing `Model` layer, not present in Symfony2, and make it to give *"the logic"* of the domain objects, completely separated and decoupled from the layer of data-persistence which knows *"how to store"* the model into a MySQL database with doctrine, or to a redis, or simply to a text file.

All those storage systems should be interchangeable and your `Model` should still expose the very same public methods with absolutely no change to the consumer.

Here's how you do it:

**Step 1: Separate the model from the data-persistence**

To do so, in your bundle, you can create another directory named `Model` at the bundle-root level (besides `tests`, `DependencyInjection` and so), as in this example of a game.

[image: Model should be a separated layer different from the persistence layer]

- The name `Model` is not mandatory, Symfony does not say anything about it. You can choose whatever you want.
- If your project is simple (say one bundle), you can create that directory inside the same bundle.
- If your project is many bundles wide, you could consider

  - either putting the model splitted in the different bundles, or
  - or -as in the example image- use a ModelBundle that contains all the "objects" the project needs (no interfaces, no controllers, no commands, just the logic of the game, and its tests). In the example, you see a `ModelBundle`, providing logical concepts like `Board`, `Piece` or `Tile` among many others, structures in directories for clarity.

**Particularly for your question**

In your example, you could have:

```
Entity/People.php
Model/People.php
```

- Anything related to "store" should go inside `Entity/People.php` - Ex: suppose you want to store the birthdate both in a date-time field, as well as in three redundant fields: year, month, day, because of any tricky things related to search or indexing, that are not domain-related (ie not related withe lo 'logics' of a person).
- Anything related to the "logics" should go inside `Model/People.php` - Ex: how to calculate if a person is over the majority of age just now, given a certain birthdate and the country he lives (which will determine the minumum age). As you can see, this has nothing to do on the persistence.

**Step 2: Use factories**

Then, you must remember that the consumers of the model, should **never ever** create model objects using "new". They should use a factory instead, that will setup the model objects properly (will bind to the proper data-storage layer). The only exception is in unit-testing (we'll see it later). But apart from unitary tests, grab this with fire in your brain, and tattoo it with a laser in your retina: Never do a 'new' in a controller or a command. Use the factories instead ;)

To do so, you create a service that acts as the "getter" of your model. You create the getter as a factory accessible thru a service. See the image:

[image: Use a service as a factory to get your model]

You can see a `BoardManager.php` there. It is the factory. It acts as the main getter for anything related to boards. In this case, the BoardManager has methods like the following:

```
public function createBoardFromScratch( $width, $height )
public function loadBoardFromJson( $document )
public function loadBoardFromTemplate( $boardTemplate )
public function cloneBoard( $referenceBoard )
```

- Then, as you see in the image, in the `services.yml` you define that manager, and you inject the persistence layer into it. In this case, you inject the `ObjectStorageManager` into the `BoardManager`. The `ObjectStorageManager` is, for this example, able to store and load objects from a database or from a file; while the `BoardManager` is storage agnostic.
- You can see also the `ObjectStorageManager` in the image, which in turn is injected the @doctrine to be able to access the `mysql`.
- Your managers are the only place where a `new` is allowed. Never in a controller or command.

**Particularly for your question**

In your example, you would have a `PeopleManager` in the model, able to get the people objects as you need.

Also in the Model, you should use the proper singular-plural names, as this is decoupled from your data-persistence layer. Seems you are currently using `People` to represent a single `Person` - this can be because you are currently (wrongly) matching the model to the database table name.

So, involved model classes will be:

```
PeopleManager -> the factory
People -> A collection of persons.
Person -> A single person.
```

For example (pseudocode! using C++ notation to indicate the return type):

```
PeopleManager
{
    // Examples of getting single objects:
    Person getPersonById( $personId ); -> Load it from somewhere (mysql, redis, mongo, file...)
    Person ClonePerson( $referencePerson ); -> Maybe you need or not, depending on the nature the your problem that your program solves.
    Person CreatePersonFromScratch( $name, $lastName, $birthDate ); -> returns a properly initialized person.

    // Examples of getting collections of objects:
    People getPeopleByTown( $townId ); -> returns a collection of people that lives in the given town.
}

People implements ArrayObject
{
    // You could overload assignment, so you can throw an exception if any non-person object is added, so you can always rely on that People contains only Person objects.
}

Person
{
    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $birthday;
}
```

So, continuing with your example, when you do...

```
// **Never ever** do a new from a controller!!!
$som1 = new People('Paul', 'Smith', '1970-01-01');
$som1->getAge();
```

...you now can mutate to:

```
// Use factory services instead:
$peopleManager = $this->get( 'myproject.people.manager' );
$som1 = $peopleManager->createPersonFromScratch( 'Paul', 'Smith', '1970-01-01' );
$som1->getAge();
```

The PeopleManager will do the `new`for you.

At this point, your variable `$som1` of type `Person`, as it was created by the factory, can be pre-populated with the necessary mechanics to store and save to the persistence layer.

The `myproject.people.manager` will be defined in your `services.yml` and will have access to the doctrine either directly, either via a 'myproject.persistence.manager` layer or whatever.

Note: This injection of the persistence layer via the manager, has several side effects, that would side track from "how to make the model have access to services". See steps 4 and 5 for that.

**Step 3: Inject the services you need via the factory.**

Now you can inject any services you need into the people.manager

You, if your model object needs to access that service, you have now 2 choices:

- When the factory creates a model object, (ie when PeopleManager creates a Person) to inject it via either the constructor, either a setter.
- Proxy the function in the PeopleManager and inject the PeopleManager thru the constructor or a setter.

In this example, we provide the PeopleManager with the service to be consumed by the model. When the people manager is requested a new model object, it injects the service needed to it in the `new` sentence, so the model object can access the external service directly.

```
// Example of injecting the low-level service.
class PeopleManager
{
    private $externalService = null;

    class PeopleManager( ServiceType $externalService )
    {
        $this->externalService = $externalService;
    }

    public function CreatePersonFromScratch()
    {
        $externalService = $this->externalService;
        $p = new Person( $externalService );
    }
}

class Person
{
    private $externalService = null;

    class Person( ServiceType $externalService )
    {
        $this->externalService = $externalService;
    }

    public function ConsumeTheService()
    {
        $this->externalService->nativeCall();  // Use the external API.
    }
}

// Using it.
$peopleManager = $this->get( 'myproject.people.manager' );
$person = $peopleManager->createPersonFromScratch();
$person->consumeTheService()
```

In this example, we provide the PeopleManager with the service to be consumed by the model. Nevertheless, when the people manager is requested a new model object, it injects **itself** to the object created, so the model object can access the external service via the manager, which then hides the API, so if ever the external service changes the API, the manager can do the proper conversions for all the consumers in the model.

```
// Second example. Using the manager as a proxy.
class PeopleManager
{
    private $externalService = null;

    class PeopleManager( ServiceType $externalService )
    {
        $this->externalService = $externalService;
    }

    public function createPersonFromScratch()
    {
        $externalService = $this->externalService;
        $p = new Person( $externalService);
    }

    public function wrapperCall()
    {
         return $this->externalService->nativeCall();
    }
}

class Person
{
    private $peopleManager = null;

    class Person( PeopleManager $peopleManager )
    {
        $this->peopleManager = $peopleManager ;
    }

    public function ConsumeTheService()
    {
        $this->peopleManager->wrapperCall(); // Use the manager to call the external API.
    }
}

// Using it.
$peopleManager = $this->get( 'myproject.people.manager' );
$person = $peopleManager->createPersonFromScratch();
$person->ConsumeTheService()
```

**Step 4: Throw events for everything**

At this point, you can use any service in any model. Seems all is done.

Nevertheless, when you implement it, you will find problems at decoupling the model with the entity, if you want a truly SOLID pattern. This also applies to decoupling this model from other parts of the model.

The problem clearly arises at places like "when to do a flush()" or "when to decide if something must be saved or left to be saved later" (specially in long-living PHP processes), as well as the problematic changes in case the doctrine changes its API and things like this.

But is also true when you want to test a Person without testing its House, but the House must "monitor" if the Person changes its name to change the name in the mailbox. This is specially try for long-living processes.

The solution to this is to use the observer pattern ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern ) so your model objects throw events nearly for anything and an observer decides to cache data to RAM, to fill data or to store data to the disk.

This strongly enhances the solid/closed principle. You should never change your model if the thing you change is not domain-related. For example adding a new way of storing to a new type of database, should require **zero** edition on your model classes.

You can see an example of this in the following image. In it, I highlight a bundle named "TurnBasedBundle" that is like the core functionality for every game that is turn-based, despite if it has a board or not. You can see that the bundle only has Model and Tests.

Every game has a ruleset, players, and during the game, the players express the desires of what they want to do.

In the `Game` object, the instantiators will add the **ruleset** (poker? chess? tic-tac-toe?). Caution: what if the ruleset I want to load does not exist?

When initializing, someone (maybe the /start controller) will add **players**. Caution: what if the game is 2-players and I add three?

And during the game the controller that receives the players movements will add **desires** (for example, if playing chess, "the player wants to move queen to this tile" -which may be a valid, or not-.

In the picture you can see those 3 actions under control thanks to the events.

[image: Example of throwing events from the model for virtually everything that can happen]

- You can observe that the bundle has only Model and Tests.
- In the model, we define our 2 objects: Game, and the GameManager, to get instances of Game objects.
- We also define Interfaces, like for example the GameObserver, so anyone willing to receive the Game events should be a GameObserver folk.
- Then you can see that for any action that modifies the state of the model (for example adding a player), I have 2 events: `PRE` and `POST`. See how it works:

1. Someone calls the $game->addPlayer( $player ) method.
2. As soon as we enter the addPlayer() function, the `PRE` event is raised.
3. The observers then can catch this event to decide if a player can be added or not.
4. All `PRE` events should come with a cancel passed by reference. So if someone decides this is a game for 2 players and you try to add a 3rd one, the $cancel will be set to true.
5. Then you are again inside the addPlayer function. You can check if someone wanted to cancel the operation.
6. Do the operation if allowed (ie: mutate the $this-> state).
7. After the state has been changed, raise a `POST` event to indicate the observers that the operation has been completed.

In the picture you see three, but of course it has a lot lot more. As a rule of thumb, you will have nearly 2 events per setter, 2 events per method that can modify the state of the model and 1 event for each "unavoidable" action. So if you have 10 methods on a class that operate on it, you can expect to have about 15 or 20 events.

You can easily see this in the typical simple text box of any graphyc library of any operating system: Typical events will be: gotFocus, lostFocus, keyPress, keyDown, keyUp, mouseDown, mouseMove, etc...

**Particularly, in your example**

The Person will have something like preChangeAge, postChangeAge, preChangeName, postChangeName, preChangeLastName, postChangeLastName, in case you have setters for each of them.

For long-living actions like "person, do walk for 10 seconds" you maybe have 3: preStartWalking, postStartWalking, postStopWalking (in case a stop of 10 seconds cannot be programatically prevented).

If you want to simplify, you can have two single `preChanged( $what, & $cancel )` and `postChanged( $what )` events for everything.

If you never prevent your changes to happen, you can even just have one single event `changed()` for all and any change to your model. Then your entity will just "copy" the model properties in the entity properties at every change. This is OK for simple classes and projects or for structures you are not going to publish for third-party consumers, and saves some coding. If the model class becomes a core class to your project, spending a bit of time adding all the events list will save you time in the future.

**Step 5: Catch the events from the data layer.**

It is at this point that your data-layer bundle enters in action!!!

Make your data layer an observer of your model. When the model Changes its internal state then make your Entity to "copy" that state into the entity state.

In this case, the MVC acts as expected: The Controller, operates on the Model. The consequences of this are still hidden from the controller (as the controller should not have access to Doctrine). The model "broadcasts" the operation made, so anyone interested knows, which in turn triggers that the data-layer knows about the model change.

**Particularly, in your project**

The `Model/Person` object will have been created by the `PeopleManager`. When creating it, the `PeopleManager`, which is a service, and therefore can have other services injected, can have the `ObjectStorageManager` subsystem handy. So the `PeopleManager` can get the `Entity/People` that you reference in your question and add the `Entity/People` as an observer to `Model/Person`.

In the `Entity/People` mainly you substitute all the setters by event catchers.

You read your code like this: When the `Model/Person` changes its LastName, the `Entity/People` will be notified and will copy the data into its internal structure.

Most probably, you are tempted to inject the entity inside the model, so instead of throwing an event, you call the setters of the Entity.

But with that approach, you 'break' the Open-Closed principle. So if at any given point you want to migrate to MongoDb, you need to "change" your "entities" by "documents" in your model. With the observer-pattern, this change occurs outside the model, who never knows the nature of the observer beyond that is its a PersonObserver.

**Step 6: Unit test everything**

Finally, you want to unit test your software. As this pattern I have explained overcomes the anti-pattern that you discovered, you can (and you should) unit-test the logics of your model independently of how that is stored.

Following this pattern, helps you to go towards the SOLID principles, so each "unit of code" is independent on the others. This will allow you to create unit-tests that will test the "logics" of your `Model` without writing to the database, as it will inject a fake data-storage layer as a test-double.

Let me use the game example again. I show you in the image the Game test. Assume all games can last several days and the starting datetime is stored in the database. We in the example currently test only if getStartDate() returns a dateTime object.

[image]

There are some arrows in it, that represent the flow.

In this example, from the two injecting strategies I told you, I choose the first one: To inject into the `Game` model object the services it needs (in this case a `BoardManager`, `PieceManager` and `ObjectStorageManager`) and not to inject the `GameManager` itself.

1. First, you invoke phpunit that will call look for the Tests directory, recursively in all the directories, finding classes named XxxTest. Then will desire to invoke all the methods named textSomething().
2. But before calling it, for each test method it calls the setup().
3. In the setup we will create some test-doubles to avoid "real access" to the database when testing, while correctly testing the logics in our model. In this case a double of my own data layer manager, `ObjectStorageManager`.
4. It is assigned to a temporary variable for clarity...
5. ...that is stored in the GameTest instance...
6. ...for later use in the test itself.
7. The $sut (system under test) variable is then created with a `new` command, not via a manager. Do you remember that I said that tests were an exception? If you use the manager (you still can) here it is not a unit-test, it's an integration test because tests two classes: the manager and the game. In the `new` command we fake all the dependencies that the model has (like a board manager, and like a piece manager). I am hardcoding GameId = 1 here. This relates to data-persistance, see below.
8. We then may call the system under test (a simple `Game` model object) to test its internals.

I am hardcoding "Game id = 1" in the `new`. In this case we are only testing that the returned type is a DateTime object. But in case we want to test also that the date that it gets is the proper one, we can "tune" the ObjectStorageManager (data-persistance layer) mock to return whatever we want in the internal call, so we could test that for example when I request the date to the data-layer for game=1 the date is 1st-jun-2014 and for game=2 the date is 2nd-jun-2014. Then in the testGetStartDate I would create 2 new instances, with Ids 1 and 2 and check the content of the result.

**Particularly, in your project**

You will have a `Test/Model/PersonTest` unit test that will be able to play with the logics of the person, and in case of needing a person from the database, you will fake it thru the mock.

In case you want to test the storing of the person to the database, it is enough that you unit-test that the event is thrown, no matter who listens to it. You can create a fake listener, attach to the event, and when the `postChangeAge` happens mark a flag and do nothing (no real database storage). Then you assert that the flag is set.

**In short:**

1. Do not confuse logics and data-persistance. Create a `Model` that has nothing to do with entities, and put all the logics in it.
2. Do never use `new` to get your models from any consumer. Use factory services instead. Special attention to avoid news in controllers and commands. Exception: The unit-test is the only consumer that can use a `new`.
3. Inject the services you need in the Model via the factory, which in turn receives it from the services.yml configuration file.
4. Throw events for everything. When I say everything, means everything. Just imagine you observe the model. What would you like to know? Add an event for it.
5. Catch the events from controllers, views, commands and from other parts of the model, but, specially, catch them in the data-storage layer, so you can "copy" the object to the disk without being intrusive to the model.
6. Unit test your logics without depending on any real database. Attach the real database storage system in production and attach a dummy implementation for your tests.

Seems a lot of work. But it is not. It is a matter of getting used to it. Just think about the "objects" you need, create them and make the data-layer be "monitors" of your objects. Then your objects are free to run, decoupled. If you create the model from a factory, inject any needed service in the model to the model, and leave the data alone.

### Edit apr/2016 - Separating Domain from Persistance

All occurences of the word **entity** in this answer are referring to the "doctrine entities" which is what causes confusion to the majority of coders, between the **model layer** and the **persistance layer** which should be always different.

- **Doctrine** is infrastructure, so *doctrine is outside the model* by definition.
- Doctrine has **entities**. So, by definition, then *doctrine entities are also outside the model*.
- Instead, the increasing popularity of the `DDD` building blocks makes a need to clarify even more my answer, as `DDD` uses the word `Entity` within the model too.
- `Domain entities` (not `Doctrine entities`) are similar to what I refer in this answer to `Domain objects`.
- In fact, there are many types of `Domain objects`:

  - `Domain entities` (different from the `Doctrine entites`).
  - `Domain value objects` (could be thought similar to basic types, with logic).
  - `Domain events` (also distinct from those `Symfony events` and also different from the `Doctrine events`).
  - `Domain commands` (different from those `Symfony command line` controller-like helpers).
  - `Domain services` (different from the `Symfony framework services`).
  - etc.
- Therefore, take all my explanation as this: when I say "Entities are not model objects" just read "Doctrine entities are not Domain entities".

### Edit jun/2019 - CQRS+ES analogy

Ancients already used persistant history methods to recod things (for example placing marks on a stone to register transactions).

Since a decade long the CQRS+ES approach (Command Query Responsability Segregation + Event Sourcing) in programming has been growing in popularity, bringing that idea of "the history is immutable" to the programs we code and today many coders think of separating the command side vs the query side. If you don't know what I'm talking about, no worries, just skip the next paragraphs.

The growing popularity of CQRS+ES in the last 3 or 4 years makes me think to consider a comment here and how it relates to what I answered here 5 years ago:

This answer was thought as 1 single model, not a write-model and a read-model. But I'm happy to see many overlapping ideas.

Think of the PRE events, I mention here, as the "commands and the write-model". Think of the POST events as the "Event Sourcing part going towards the read-model".

In CQRS you can easily find that "commands can be accepted or not" in function of the internal state. Usually one implements them throwing exceptions but there are other alternatives there, like answering if the command was accepted or not.

For example, in a "Train" I can "set it to X speed". But if the state is that the train is in a rail that cannot go further 80Km/h, then setting it to 200 should be rejected.

This is ANALOGOUS to the `cancel` boolean passed by reference where an entity could just "reject" something PRIOR to its state change.

Instead the POST events do not carry the "cancel" event and are thrown AFTER the state change happened. This is why you could not cancel them: They talk about the "state change that actually occurred" and therefore it cannot be cancelled: It aleady happened.

So...

In my answer of 2014, the "pre" events match with the "Command acceptance" of the CQRS+ES systems (the command can be accepted or rejected), and the "post" events match the "Domain events" of the CQRS+ES systems (it just informs that the change actually already happened, do whatever you want with that information).

Comment: Hi @Xavi, thx for your very detailled answer. As you can easily imagine, it creates loads of questions myside, and it's not easy to sum them up in 500 characters. So i'm going to post one comment per question.

Comment: **Step 2 : use factories** it seems like the factory is acting both like the entity mananger (it does the `new` )AND the repository (it `gets` collection of objects). Do i get it right?

Comment: **Step 2 : use factories** you write : `$som1 = $peopleManager->createPersonFromScratch( 'Paul', 'Smith', '1970-01-01' );`. Do you confirm createPersonFromScratch creates an Entity/Person (and not a Model/Person) ?

Comment: **Step3 : inject the services** : you write : "_when the people manager is requested a new model object, it injects itself to the object created, so the model object can access the external service via the manager, which then hides the API_" **so the manager create a model object and not en entity object?** "_it injects itself to the object created_" then you write **a class inside a class?** `class PeopleManager{private attribute {class PeopleManager (variable??)}}` is it a typing mistake, **did you mean a method?** Last but not least, **what are you refering to when you speak about API?**

Comment: **Step3 : inject the services** in your class PeopleManger where does `$this->serviceToInject` comes from? `public function ConsumeTheService()` would that be my getAge() function for example? and what is `$this->externalService->nativeCall();` ?

Comment: **Step 4 : throw events for everything** no questions at the moment

Comment: **Step 5 : catch the event from the data layer** there you write black on white "_the PeopleManager created a Model/Person_", so it's answering comment #3.

Comment: **Step 5 : catch the event from the data layer** "_in Entity/People mainly you substitute all the setters by event catcher (...) and Entity/People will copy [the Model/Person changes]_ into its internal structure"... i get the principle but cant figure how this get done? who is persisting/flushing the changes? ObjectStorageManager? how? when?

Comment: **Step 6 : unit test** more or less got it. but dont want to focus on the test right now as i first want to be certain to understand the general process first.

Comment: FINAL WORDS : your answer was going far beyond my original question, but i feel like it's actually answering the general designing problem that i've been struggling with in the past 2 months. I hope you'll take time again to answer those comments, and in advance, my apologize if some of my question seem stupid, i can insure you i been printing and studying ur answer as carefully as i could

Comment: Hey @Developpertunisie, answering comment by comment. BTW Don't worry about the level of your questions (as per your last comment). Sometimes asking a silly question and posting the answer, not only unblocks you buy thousands of readers with the same problem. Happy to help ;)

Comment: **Comment #2 - Step 2: use factories** - No, this manager only relates to Model/* and has nothing to do with Entity/* (as you have discovered yourself). In the case you "translate" real entities to your modelled objects, or if you imagine that the events in the model will trigger the loading from the database thru an external data provider, then you can think of this as either an entity manager and a repository. But to avoid confusion, just imagine that it's an "object getter" to get objects from the model. And imagine that collections are also objets.

Comment: **Comment #3 - Step 2: use factories -** As you have discovered yourself later, this gets Model/Person, not Entity/Person. It's a manager to get objects from the model. The data will come automatically from event handling.

Comment: **Comment #4 - Step3: inject the services - Question 1 -** As said, the manager creates a model object.

Comment: **Comment #4 - Step3: inject the services - Question 2 -** You do not write a class inside a class. Just store the service as any other variable. When I say "inject the service", I mean at runtime. Code is as separate classes. In the services.yml configure it and pass the service thru the constructor, or if you prefer, via a setter. Just store `$this->savedService = $passedService;` in the constructor or setter. Later at any method, use the service `$this->savedService->methodInService();`

Comment: **Comment #4 - Step3: inject the services - Question 4 -** I'm not talking here about remote calls (REST apis or whatever). The same way when you program for Windows or Linux and want to call something of the operating system, you call the "OS API" meaning a set of C functions, when you are in Object Orientation, the API is simply a) the class list, b) for each class, the list of methods (and public properties, public constants, etc if any), c) for each method, the return type and the accepted parameters and their types. In short: The info you'd give to another person that codes a consumer.

Comment: **Comment #5 - Step 3: inject the services - Question 1 -** Sorry I made a typo. `$serviceToInject` was in fact `$externalService`. So it comes from the constructor. It is stored in `$this->externalService` and later can be consumed from there. I've already edited my post to reflect the proper sample code.

Comment: **Comment #5 - Step 3: inject the services - Questions 2 and 3 -** What you inject is a class, for example the service that contains your getAge() method. So think instead of `$externalService` a better name like `$dateManipulatorService`. Then you would store `$this->dateManipulatorService` in the constructor and then, wherever you want in your class `$this->dateManipulatorService->getAge()` which probably lacks a bit of sense, as getAge probably needs some data and is outside the class scope. Maybe you need to pass data to it: `$this->dateManipulatorService->getAge( $this->birthDate )`

Comment: **Comment #8 - Step 5 : catch the event from the data layer -** There are two main approaches here. I like to call them "Microsoft Word vs Google Drive". In word, you press "CTRL+S" to "save" the document. In Google drive you look into the menus... and there is no "save" option, as the document is "always" saved even if you type a single letter. You must decide if you want to give the consumer the chance to "persist" the data voluntarily, or get all persisted. If you choose the first approach, then the model is "saveable" so as a model it needs a `->save()` method. --continues in next comment.

Comment: Then in `->save()` throw a `preSave` and `postSave` event. In pre you can forbid data to be saved (for example your model is in 'demo' mode and a listener just prevents to save anything). In post you know no listener forbid that (means it is 'ready' to save), so the data-layer can the catch the event and call the ->flush() if doctrine or do the direct SQL in case you don't use doctrine and your data layer is pure sql. You maybe want to add a 3rd event `aleadySaved`, or maybe rename all of them for clarity: `requestPermissionToSave`, `save` and `afterSaved`. Just be clear to your consumers.

Comment: Of course this is the `Microsoft word` approach, where you have a `->save()` in the menu. The `Google drive` approch triggers a timer at every keystroke. When you stop typing for 1 second, then performs the saving of all those things you have typed simulating an illusion of real-time saving. You are in risk of loosing some letters, anyway. If you do an invociing system, you need to ensure persistance. If you are doing a social network, you can cope with loosing a photo if it is uploaded "just at the very same moment" than your servers crash. You put your effors in servers not crashing ;)

Comment: You can also encounter different possible patterns if yours is a short-living PHP (called from the web server, runs and dies at every request), or a long-living PHP process (say, launched at command-line and can stay live for days listening to inputs from sockets or AMQP's and answering to those requests. In the first case (short living), in a company I worked for, what we did is just put the `->flush()` in the destructor of the service of the data layer. So each time the script finished, flushed all. No need to call any `->save()` in the model.

Comment: For long-living either you put a `->save()` in the model (Microsoft word approach) or automatically save at each setter of the model (can be a bit overloading) or if you can cope with async save, trigger a timer at each setter, and save on the timer timeout (Google drive approach). If there are no server crashes, the Model consumer never sees a save(). What if another consumer needs the updated data? No matter, as it should use the model (which is already in RAM and with updated data). It's not yet on disk, but it's available in RAM for all the consumers as it is a single long-living process.

Comment: **Comment #9 - Step 6: Unit test -** I suggest you start doing unit test of your model as soon as you start writing it. It's like a drug. Once you learn unit testing, you can't live without it ;) - Unit test does **not only** serve to regression tests (break things accidentally) but for me **the major power of it** is that helps you to discover anti-patterns as the most anti-pattern you are, the most impossible is the test ;) and on the other side, the most testable your soft, the bigger probability you are in a good pattern.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60484/discussion-on-answer-by-xavi-montero-sf2-using-a-service-inside-an-entity).

Comment: I think events in the model are good but re: interacting with entities, another option is to have the model specify a repository interface that it accepts and works with. The repository interface may have save(), find() etc. The model interacts with the repository (not caring about the implementation). You can inject whatever repository implementation you'd like. Perhaps an "in memory" implementation for tests, or a "doctrine" implementation, or a "mongo" implementation.

Comment: @XaviMontero Interesting, it deserves to be blog post.

Comment: Here in stack overflow? (in this case I didn't know it is possible to create blogs here) or in another place, you mean?

Comment: @XaviMontero thank you for this awesome and exhaustive answer. Could you please also publish something like a project template (probably on github and leave a link in your answer) which would contain all code you mentioned above? i.e. a full example, say for one model, one collection of models, controller, persistance layer and tests?

Comment: @DmitryWojciechowski I was thinking about it. Unfortunately I don't have too much time now, but that's a pending task I have in my to-do list. I'm starting a videogames project in unity, besides my normal work at http://reactable.com. If any of you can help me in that videogames adventure, maybe I may free some time and do that tutorial :D

Comment: @XaviMontero dont forget to update your answer if tutorial comes out :)

Comment: @XaviMontero I'm sorry. I know this is an old answer, but I've just stumbled upon it, and I think it should be corrected.

"Doctrine has entities. So, by definition, then doctrine entities are also outside the model."

No. You've based your answer upon this assumption, which is wrong. Doctrine doesn't have any entities. Doctrine ORM maps *your entities* (base blocks of problem domain model) to a relational database. Hence the name ORM.

Please checkout this presentation (from Doctrine lead developer) for clarification:
https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/

Comment: @XaviMontero you insist on separation between business logic from data persistence, i think it is good approach but most expensive one , imagine I have an entity with 10 relationship and each relationship might have other relationships init then if i want to map my model to entity each time I must do lots of actions just for mapping, in this article https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/ the author said it is very expensive to separate them

Comment: @XaviMontero , but i wonder to know your opinion about this huge mapping and extra operations we must do each time, also doctrine entity class is a simple php object and it is pure? and second question is about repository we you do not use it?

Comment: To avoid converting comments into a discussion forum, which could result in StackOvervlow moderators calling us attention; and provided they are 2 questions that "per se" are important themselves, I'd suggest you create new deeply-written questions in StackOverflow (either two questions, or one question with the two inside), then paste the link and then we delete the last comments leaving only the links. And I'll do my best to try to respond to those questions, taking advantage of all the tools this fantastic platform provides to us and keeping the structure clean. What do you feel?

Answer (score 2):

You already mentioned a very good point. Instances of class `Person` are not the only thing that can have an age. `BlogArticle`s can also age along with many other types. If you're using PHP 5.4+ you can utilize traits to add little pieces of functionality instead of having service objects from the container (or maybe you can combine them).

Here is a quick mockup of what you could do to make it very flexible. This is the basic idea:

- Have one age calculating trait (`Aging`)
- Have a specific trait which can return the appropriate field (`$birthdate`, `$createdDate`, ...)
- Use the trait inside your class

---

#### Generic

```
trait Aging {
    public function getAge() { 
        return $this->calculate($this->start()); 
    }

    public function calculate($startDate) { ... }
}
```

#### For person

```
trait AgingPerson {
    use Aging;
    public function start() {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }   
}

class Person {
    use AgingPerson;
    private $birthDate = '1999-01-01'; 
}
```

#### For blog article

```
// Use for articles, pages, news items, ...
trait AgingContent {
    use Aging;
    public function start() {
        return $this->createdDate;
    }   
}

class BlogArticle {
    use AgingContent;
    private $createDate = '2014-01-01'; 
}
```

---

Now you can ask any instance of the above classes for their age.

```
echo (new Person())->getAge();
echo (new BlogArticle())->getAge();
```

---

#### Finally

If you need type hinting traits won't do you any favors. In that case you will need to provide an interface and let every class that uses the trait implement it (the actual implementation is the trait but the interface enables type hinting).

```
interface Ageable {
    public function getAge();
}

class Person implements Ageable { ... }
class BlogArticle implements Ageable { ... }

function doSomethingWithAgeable(Ageable $object) { ... }
```

This may seem like a lot of hassle when in reality it's much easier to maintain and extend this way.

Answer (score 1):

A big part is that there is no easy way to inject dependencies when using the database.

```
$person = $personRepository->find(1); // How to get the age service injected?
```

One solution might be to pass the age service as an argument.

```
$ageCalculator = $container('age_service');

$person = $personRepository->find(1);

$age = $person->calcAge($ageCalculator);
```

But really, you would probably be better off just adding the age stuff to your Person class.  Easier to test and all that.

It sounds like you might have some output formatting going on?  That sort of thing should probably be done in twig.  getAge should really just return a number.

Likewise, your date of birth really should be a date object and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it's generally discouraged. However, there are several approaches how you can extend the functionality of an entity beyond the purpose of a data container. Of course, all of them can be considered (more or less) bad practice … but somehow you gotta do the job, right?

1. You can indeed create an `AbstractEntity` super class, from which all other entities inherit. This AbstractEntity would contain helper methods that other entities may need.
2. You can work with [custom Doctrine repositories](http://mackstar.com/blog/2010/10/04/using-repositories-doctrine-2), if you need an entity context to work with an entity manager and return “more special” results than what the common getters would give you. As you have access to the entity manager in a repository, you can perform all kinds of special queries.
3. You can write a service that is in charge of the entity/entities in question. Downside: you cannot control that other parts of your code (or other developers) know of this service. Advantage: There's no limit to what you can do, and it's all nicely encapsuled.
4. You can work with [Lifecycle Events/Callbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html).
5. If you really need to inject services into entities, you could consider setting a static property on the entity and only set it once in a controller or a dedicated service. Then you don't need to take care on each initialization of an object. Could be combined with the AbstractEntity approach.

As mentioned before, all of these are have their advantages and disadvantages. Pick your poison.